# DJANGO get access token

Tags: django, python-3.x, oauth-2.0

When I'm running the first-time log in API using username and password will get the client id and secret. using o/token api I will get the access token, o/token params are as follows:

```
 grant_type=password username={{emailid}} password={{password}} client_id={{client id}} client_secret={{client secret}}
```

Is it possible to get the access token without using username and password in o/token/ api? using the only client_id and client secret can I get access token and refresh token???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally got solution!!!!!!

We have to use oauth2 client_credentials grant type instead of password type. For more info check this out - https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749#section-4.4